# Schwarz Inequality Proof (Dirac Notation)

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am trying to prove Schwarz Inequality by following the QM book by R. Shankar. I got almost to the end where I am having trouble.

I have noticed that there are similar questions on this website, but no one provided the answer I am looking for.

I would greatly appreciate it if you can help me with the missing steps. Also, do point out if I have made any mistakes. Attached is what I have. Sorry for not typing it in LaTeX, I did this in a hurry.

Thank you for your time!

[image]
[image]

There is actually a mistake here. The >= sign in the end result should be <=. So, it is |<V|W>| <= |V||W| (Schwarz Inequality).

---

### UPDATE (SOLVED)

Below is the completed proof. Thanks to @Malkoun for helping me out in the comments!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is written is basically correct. $<v|v> = |v|^2$ and $<v|w><w|v> = |<v|w>|^2$. Then after you take the square root on both sides at the end, you get Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I saw from my equations that, provided that they are correct, that would  follow

<v|w><w|v> = |<v|w>|^2.

However, how did you get this? In other words, that should be the same as 

<v|w><v|w>* = |<v|w>|^2.

But I don't see why is that because of the complex conjugate. Inner product space should lose symmetry (it has skew-symmetry) compared to "regular" dot product, so how is this the same?

I would really appreciate if you make this clear to me. :)

Comment: The Dirac braket, known as an hermitian inner product in more mathematical circles, has the following property: $<w|v>$ is the complex conjugate of $<v|w>$ (which you are denoting by a $*$, following physicists notation). Also note that given $v$ and $w$, $<v|w>$ is a complex number. Moreover if $z \in \mathbb{C}$, say $z=x+iy$ ($x$, $y$ real), then if you multiply $z$ by its complex conjugate, you get: $zz^* = z^*z = x^2+y^2 = |z|^2$ (where $*$ denotes the complex conjugate).

Comment: @Malkoun THANK YOU SO MUCH. After just learning about the Dirac notation and not being very comfortable with it, I completely forgot to think of <V|W> as a complex number (sclar value). This was so obvious, but thank you anyway!!!

Comment: you're welcome.

Comment: By the way, and though you have a nice hand-writing, try to type in LaTeX on this website (for next time). I am glad I could help.